# The current request is not a multipart request

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, spring-boot

On uploading my file by ajax I am facing Exeption

> org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request

I google this and find many solution,applied all of them no one resolved my problem-

Below is my `html-file`

```
<form id="upload-file-form">
   <label for="upload-file-input">Upload your file:</label>
   <input id="upload-file-input" type="file" name="uploadfile" accept="*" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
</form>
```

Script for ajax-

```
$.ajax({
         url: "/util/uploadFile",
         type: "POST",
         data: {'uploadfile':new FormData($("#upload-file-form")[0])},
         enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
         processData: false,
         contentType: false,
         cache: false,
         success: function () {},
         error: function () {}
         });
```

And this is my Spring boot Controller("/util")-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("uploadfile") MultipartFile uploadfile) {
        System.out.println("----------------");
        System.out.println("----------------" + uploadfile);
        return "success";
    }


    @Bean
    public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        return new MultipartConfigElement("");
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(4000000);
        return multipartResolver;
    }
```

Comment: Try to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in `form` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending an Ajax request and `you are using name of input field directly in your controller` which cause the problem. Because when ajax request come to the `controller it doesn't found any parameter with name "uploadfile"` that's why it giving you error.

Here I've just put key for the file and it accept request. The code written below is work for me.

Ajax code,

```
var formData = new FormData();
var file = $('#fileInputId')[0].files[0];

formData.append("myFileKey", file);

$.ajax({
        url : 'myUrl',
        type : 'POST',
        data : formData,
        enctype : 'multipart/form-data',
        contentType : false,
        cache : false,
        processData : false,
        success : function(response) {},
        error: function(){}    
     )};
```

Java Controller Code:,

```
    @PostMapping(value = { "/myUrl" }, consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
    public ModelAndView readFileData(@RequestParam("myFileKey") MultipartFile uploadedFile) throws IOException 
   {
                 Your Stuff...... 
   }
```